# Selenium Can't find "HOME" element on Facebook

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing some exercises with selenium, trying to scrape a few pages on facebook.
However, I'm not able to find the "Home" button link element to keep going. This on the left menu  in any user's profile.

[image]

From what I'm seeing in the page code, the link is here:

```
<div class="_2yaa" data-key="tab_home">
  <a class="_2yau" data-endpoint="/seudogshow/?ref=page_internal" href="/seudogshow/?ref=page_internal">
    <span class="_2yav">Home</span>
    <span class="img _55ym _55yn _55yo _2wwb" aria-busy="true" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuetext="Loading..."></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

How would you guys go about clicking this button?

I tried with something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Home')]").click()
```

or

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Home')]"))).click()
```

But I'm clearly doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you are trying to click has a `span` tag, not `a`. Try the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Home')]").click()
```